# Making a facebook app that modifies the 'create event' forms

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I just signed up as a facebook developer, and I have an idea that I'd like to pursue - the problem is that I am not sure it is even possible.
My app would add some functionality to facebook events - like when people throw parties - but i don't know if it is possible.

So I am writing to ask anyone familiar with the Facebook SDKs for some insights, help or direction. I tried to write to developer support people at facebook, but got no response, and the site says to come here...

The basic idea is to allow event hosts who install this app to modify the way their invites look, so that event guests can click on a button or link and take advantage of some features I provide.

If you have any idea where I should look for articles about how to do this, or where in the facebook documentation i should look, please let me know.

Comment: No that is not possible. The API doesn't make it possible to change Facebook.com

Comment: Thanks WizKid - I expected that answer, but was hoping there might be a way around it - oh well...